# Enabling non root user to run tomcat with port 443

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tomcat, tomcat8

I am trying to run tomcat with https as a non-root user. Configured server.xml with required port modification and added SSL configuration.

However when I execute `sudo systemctl restart tomcat` get following error in catalina.out

```
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]
      java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/permission-denied-error-when-binding-a-port-290750651.html) post

Resolution point number 5 works better

```
# setcap cap_net_bind_service+ep /path/to/bin/java
```

Comment: While this will do the trick, it's worth noting that this will allow any application using that Java install to run low ports.