# starting tomcat 9 under non-root user

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu-16.04, tomcat9

Apologies for perhaps a silly question, but I only have little experience with Tomcat (and Linux in general). 
I have launched a fresh AWS Ubuntu 16.04, installed Java 8 (for our app compatibility requirements) and Tomcat9 (in /opt/tomcat9 folder). I have created a tomcat9 user under which I intend to run Tomcat. I have copied the ssl certificate to /etc/ssl-keystore and set up ssl connector in **server.xml**

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" keystoreFile="/etc/ssl-keystore/mycert.pfx"
keystorePass="mypassword" port="443" scheme="https" secure="true"
sslProtocol="TLS" maxPostSize="104857600" maxHttpHeaderSize="204800" />
```

I have changed ownership of the /opt/tomcat9 folder to **tomcat9** user:

```
chown -hR tomcat9: /opt/tomcat9
```

If I start tomcat using

```
sudo -u tomcat9 /opt/tomcat9/bin/startup.sh
```

I am getting this error in **catalina.out**:

```
05-Jun-2018 12:42:39.112 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:935)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:530)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:852)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:622)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:645)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:227)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:202)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:939)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:575)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:932)
        ... 13 more
```

Can you please advise what am I missing or what permission should be added? I have spent a lot of time researching this already (incl. stackoverflow site) and read multiple tutorials but I am unable to find a relevant/useful answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: probably [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46491732/7748072) . BTW _sudo -u tomcat9_ won't work, you want **-u root** to try permissions.

Comment: since you are on aws, I would recommend to let ELB to handle SSL termination. Then you can run multiple tomcat instance behind ELB on normal port like 8080 with a normal user. Even without ELB, there should be something fronting tomcat like nginx, apache2.

Answer (score 0):

By default non-root users can't bind to privileged low ports. The first 1024 ports are restricted and you are trying to bind to 443.

If you insist on doing it instead of running on port 8080 with a [TLS termination proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy) try following answers. They suggest `setcap` to resolve it:

- [Is there a way for non-root processes to bind to “privileged” ports on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/414258/1602555)
- [Allow non-root process to bind to port 80 and 443?](https://superuser.com/a/892391)